# Magus' Spiderhawk Archetype and lack of Skill points?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Looking at the Magus' Archetype [Spiderhawk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/archetypes/paizo-fans-united/spiderhawk). They gain a lot of class skills and meager Skill Points. This archetype makes a Magus a partial Rogue. But at 2+Int mod, they either completely specialize or are spread too thin. Is there a errata that increases a Spiderhawk's skill point pool?

Answer (score 2):

There is no official errata or developer forum post about it.

Keep in mind that a magus primary stat is INT, so the designers probably thought you would gave enough skill points. A wizard, for instance, has a lot of skills, specially considering they gain *all* knowledge skills (present and future), but also gain 2+int. A level 1 wizard rarely will have an int lower than 18, so thats already 6 points.

By level 10, that wizard will certainly have at least 24 int, a total of 9 skill points per level. Remember that skill points are retroactive, if your int increases, you gain points for all character levels.